# Horizontal shifting of Menus on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Check this link [Click Me](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/ay7k1z6d/), as you can see I have 12 Menu items, but due to space constraint can't show more than 4 menus. As you can see currently only Menu1 to Menu4 is visible, other Meus are hidden.

Update: As Jsfiddle did some cleaning they deleted my fiddle, here above I posted answered fiddle.In my question one jquery part was not there.

I have two button:

> 1. Move Left by -1 (later will be referred as 'ML')
> 2. Move Right by +1 (later will be referred as 'MR')

I am trying to achieve this:

1. Click on `MR`will make menus shift along `+1`
2. Click on `ML`will make menus shift along `-1`

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer">
<input type="button" value="move left by -1" class="left" />
<input type="button" value="Move Right by +1" class="left" />
<ul id="menulist">
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
    <li>Menu 5</li>
    <li>Menu 6</li>
    <li>Menu 7</li>
    <li>Menu 8</li>
    <li>Menu 9</li>
    <li>Menu 10</li>
    <li>Menu 11</li>
    <li>Menu 12</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#outer {
    width:448px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.left {
    float:left;
}
ul, li {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
ul {
    font-size:0;    
    float:left;
    width:1400px;
}
li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    background:lightgrey;
    border:darkgrey;
    width:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:14px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at jquery's `.animate()`: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ This webpage might also help you: http://www.sanwebe.com/2011/12/jquery-move-div-leftrightupdown

Comment: not able to :(, can you please check what I am missing http://jsfiddle.net/z4sD6/

Comment: margin-left instead of left: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/z4sD6/1/

Comment: Here I added some stuff to the fiddle, play with it til you get what you want. I added some if statements to check margins before moving the menu. http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/z4sD6/2/

Comment: @ctwheels just asking, all fiddles are deleted? how to retrieve? even the fiddle link which i given in question is also deleted? do they clean site?

Comment: Jsfiddle was experiencing technical difficulties earlier today. They were attacked by spammers and had to shut their site down, I assume somewhere between shutting their site down and fixing it, they must have deleted certain jsfiddles that may have been deemed "harmful" by their systems, although there is no way to know for sure. Looking through my fiddles, it seems my fiddle of your project has also disappeared.

Comment: I've remade the jsfiddle for your project: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/ay7k1z6d/

Comment: thanks again, can you please post it as an answer so that it might help other who are looking for same. bcoz not all people will be reading our conversation. also I don't know why but this doesn't work in IE10, but works fine in chrome and firefox

Comment: See if this post helps you, I cannot test on IE as I don't have it installed (I really dislike IE) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542265/jquery-animate-marginleft-not-working-in-ie8-and-below-invalid-argument

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/NmyYw3hYzAMMQtxki1yU?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/ay7k1z6d/)

As mentioned in the comments above, if this does not work in IE, see if [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542265/jquery-animate-marginleft-not-working-in-ie8-and-below-invalid-argument) will help you

HTML

```
<div id="outer">
    <input type="button" value="move left by -1" class="left" />
    <input type="button" value="Move Right by +1" class="right" />
    <ul id="menulist">
        <li>Menu 1</li>
        <li>Menu 2</li>
        <li>Menu 3</li>
        <li>Menu 4</li>
        <li>Menu 5</li>
        <li>Menu 6</li>
        <li>Menu 7</li>
        <li>Menu 8</li>
        <li>Menu 9</li>
        <li>Menu 10</li>
        <li>Menu 11</li>
        <li>Menu 12</li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
#outer {
    width:448px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.left {
    float:left;
}
ul, li {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
ul {
    font-size:0;
    float:left;
    width:1400px;
}
li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    background:lightgrey;
    border:darkgrey;
    width:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:14px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

JS

```
$('.left').click(function () {
    if (parseInt($('#menulist').css('margin-left'), 10) >= -784) {
        $('#menulist').animate({
            'marginLeft': "-=112px" //moves left
        });
    }
});
$('.right').click(function () {
    if (parseInt($('#menulist').css('margin-left'), 10) >= 0) {
        $('#menulist').css('margin-left', '0px!important');
    } else {
        $('#menulist').animate({
            'marginLeft': "+=112px" //moves right
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: till some extent I was able to do with angular, this works in IE 10 as well, http://plnkr.co/edit/NmyYw3hYzAMMQtxki1yU?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
double

li {
        border:darkgrey;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
```

html

```
<input type="button" value="move left by -1" class="left" />
<input type="button" value="Move Right by +1" class="right" />
```

jquery

```
$('.left').click(function() {
    if($('#menulist').css('margin-left')=='-896px'){
         $('#menulist').css('margin-left','-896px!important');
    }
    else{
        $('#menulist').animate({
        'marginLeft' : "-=112px" //moves left
        });
    }
});
$('.right').click(function() {
    if($('#menulist').css('margin-left')=='0px'){
         $('#menulist').css('margin-left','0px!important');
    }
    else{
        $('#menulist').animate({
        'marginLeft' : "+=112px" //moves right
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for response, check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s66Tc/4/ when one click until we reach Menu 12, eventually button will disappear. it might look like am asking for more can we have a chain of menus which will be keep moving.